# Can Salesforce Articles have html content?

Tags: html, articles

Can we have Salesforce articles with HTML content?

Comment: can the question be little clear

Answer (score 8):

> Yes you can have salesforce articles with html content .You can create a rich text  field for an article type and insert your html code in that using html editor in rich text

[image]

Comment: in my developer edition article body not showing. how can i enable or create Article Body for HTML code

Comment: Create a rich text custom field for the body .This assumes you have a custom field on article type

Comment: already created  Rich text custom field, but that field not visible in record view(like above you shared image)

Comment: Do you have field level security turned on ? Also does your page layout has this field

Comment: Thank you, i created field in linked articals, not in Knowldge.. so rich text field is not visible. now enabled